# How to display sympy output in proper manner

Tags: python, django, sympy

I am very new to coding in Python and using the django.

My question: is it possible to get the input-format of an output I get from previous calculations? For example, if I obtain an output is like x**2 how can I get x^2 (x superscript 2) automatically?

for example: [image: i want this type of output.]

```py
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name':"suchit"})

def add(request):
    sp.init_printing(use_latex=True)
    val1 = sp.symbols('val1')
    x = sp.symbols('x')
    val1 = (request.POST['num1'])
    # val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
    # red = add('val1','val2')
    # init_printing()
    Differentiate = sp.diff(val1,x)
    Integrate = sp.integrate(val1,x)

    # result = [Differentiate,Integrate]
     # integral_steps(res)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'result': Differentiate, 'result1':  Integrate  })

    # return render(request, 'home.html ', {'name': 'add'})
```

OUTPUT is:-

```
x**2/2
```

i don't want to this type of output. i want to x superscript 2 /2 (x^2/2). check link to show that format.

Comment: Add text not as an image.

Comment: its like x raise to 2. is it possible to output in x raise to 2... not in this x^2 @shaik moeed

Comment: @shaik moeed  just check the image.. i want that type of output.. not x^2.

Comment: @helloworld922 can uh please sloved my silly problem,

Comment: @shaik moeed  i am not run on console, i am run on localhost[web]. my project is look like sympy gamma. but the output of input is not x superscript 2 format.. can you please help me?

Comment: check [this doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html). Add the code you are using, to get more help.

Comment: Split your problem. The immediate question is how to render x**2 as x^2, nothing to do with django or sympy

Answer (score 0):

sympy expressions can get pretty complicated so this gets very difficult in the general case.  HTML has MathML for this but support is [not great](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml) which complicates things

I'd therefore suggest generating [LaTeX or MathML in SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html) and also pulling in [MathJAX](https://www.mathjax.org/) to make sure it renders correctly in more browsers